# Referencing ViewModel from View's DataContext Prevents XAML Designer edits

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to "hook up" my viewmodel as a DataContext to my View. I am going with an application-wide one view-to-viewmodel scenario.

I like the idea of using the following method to attach (which it does successfully):

```
 <UserControl ......Window Stuff.......>
        <UserControl.DataContext >
             <vm:MyViewModel/>
         </UserControl.DataContext>
 </UserControl>
```

However the xaml editor places a purple squiggly line under `<vm:MyViewModel/>` and hovertext gives error

```
  "Cannot create instance of vm:MyViewModel"
```

But it correctly builds/runs my application and presents the data, which the method:

```
 <UserControl>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MyViewModel}">
             <vw:MyView/>
        </DataTemplate>
   </UserControl.Resources>
 </UserControl>
```

Does NOT present my data, although it appears to be acceptable code.

Commenting-out the DataContext reference is really a pain just for making edits to the controls manually. Am I doing something incorrectly/am I forgetting something?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: I would suggest you post your 'aside' question as a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is likely something going on in the constructor of your view model that is preventing the model from being instantiated within Visual Studio.

Try adding a `return` statement before anything is done in the view model's constructor, rebuild and see if the error goes away.

Here's an extension method that will determine if the the current process is within visual studio:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Extension method to determine if the current process is executing
    /// code within the Visual Studio designer or not.
    /// </summary>
    public static bool IsVisualStudioDesigner( this Process process )
    {
        return process.MainModule.ModuleName.Contains( "devenv.exe" );
    }
}
```

And then in your constructor:

```
public ctor()
{
  if ( Process.GetCurrentProcess().IsVisualStudioDesigner() )
    return;

  // do constructor stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, @Metro Smurf -- I actually only have the error when I'm in the designer trying to manually make changes to the controls/presentation. I can edit the xaml just fine, and the app runs perfectly, its just that there is that squiggly purple line under the viewmodel reference and I have to comment it out to make changes to the controls manually with the mouse/scroll through the designer. I will edit the post and make that more clear, I realize it was poor wording.

Comment: +1 for the correct concept, -1 for the solution.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerproperties.isindesignmode.aspx

Comment: @Will - there are times when the `IsInDesignMode` property fails. I do not recall anymore, though. In my base class I use the above plus `IsInDesignMode`, plus a DependencyProperty evaluation as well. The combination of all 3 catch Visual Studio, Expression Blend and the strange anomaly of when `IsInDesignMode` fails in VS. Agreed that I should have included the `IsInDesignMode` as an option.

Comment: @Will--do you perhaps know what is going on here (I KNOW that it is executing all the code, except for rendering the app in the Designer...I realize I poorly worded the initial phrasing of the question)?

Comment: @Rachael - the post is clear. VS is unable to create in instance of the view model. This likely the result of there being things created inside the view model that VS cannot create in design mode. Place a `return` statement at the beginning of the constructor of the view model; rebuild and see if the error goes away. If it does, then use the approach I recommended above.